# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined. I want to append a specific element but it's giving me error

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

Hi I don't know why it's saying it's undefined even tho there's an element. I am trying to append a specific element when it's clicked but it's not working tho. Can someone help me??

```
//JavaScript Document

//Constructor Function
function Movie(ptitle, pdirector, prating){
    this.title = ptitle;
    this.director = pdirector;
    this.rating = prating;
}

// 5 students and their favorite movie 
let Karen = new Movie('Parasite', 'Bong Joon-ho', 8.6);
let Sun = new Movie('Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle', 'Jake Kasdan', 6.9);
let Trisha = new Movie('Train to Busan', 'Sang-ho Yeon', 7.5);
let Jake = new Movie('Avengers: Endgame', 'Joe Russo & Anthony Russo', 8.5);
let SeoYoung = new Movie('Heneral Luna', 'Jerrold Terog', 7.6);
```

As you can see I'm using prototype function here but I don't have full knowledge on using this kind of method. I am required though to use this prototype function.

```
//Prototype method of constructor function
Movie.prototype.myMovie = function(e){

    let firstPara = ' is my favorite movie. The director of it was ';
    let secondPara = '. The rating of the movie is ';

    console.log(this.title + firstPara + this.director + secondPara + this.rating);

    let info = this.title + firstPara + this.director + secondPara + this.rating;
    e.target.appendChild(info);
}
```

This code below works properly without any issues. I am able to display the information I want in the browser.

```
//Display information in the browser
let name1 = 'Karen';
name1.id = 'karen'
let name2 = 'Sun';
name2.id = 'sun'
let name3 = 'Trisha';
name3.id = 'trisha'
let name4 = 'Jake';
name4.id = 'jake'
let name5 = 'Seo Young';
name5.id = 'seoyoung    '

let p1 = document.createElement('p');
let p2 = document.createElement('p');
let p3 = document.createElement('p');
let p4 = document.createElement('p');
let p5 = document.createElement('p');

let body = document.querySelector('body');

p1.innerHTML = name1;
p2.innerHTML = name2;
p3.innerHTML = name3;
p4.innerHTML = name4;
p5.innerHTML = name5;
body.appendChild(p1);
body.appendChild(p2);
body.appendChild(p3);
body.appendChild(p4);
body.appendChild(p5);

function showContent(){
    alert('test');
}

p1.onclick = Karen.myMovie();
```

Comment: You've defined a function `myMovie` but you never call it.

Comment: I did that but it didn't fix my problem

Comment: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at Movie.myMovie (main.js:29)
    at main.js:67

Comment: You'll want to define the `onclick` as a function itself, rather than the *result* of a function. Due to scoping of `this` you'd also need to make use of something like [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). E.g. `p1.onclick = e => Karen.myMovie.call(Karen, e);`

Comment: (The next concern would be that you can't pass a string to `appendChild`.)

Comment: The function assignment should be like this: 
p1.onclick = Karen.myMovie; //(There should not be () at the end. That will call the method instead of assigning it.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I found the solution for it now.